# Can I manage users for all B2C tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My requirement is to have Multi-tenant application.  I am trying to select the correct AD directory structure.  I am under the understanding that a tenant is an AD directory.  I need to be able to have group, role, and policy security options as well as user self sign-up.  I have started on the journey of using Azure B2C directories but this does not seem to be the correct solution because roles do not seem available. Lastly, I also need the ability to manage authorizations to all tenants which I would like to build an Admin app to do so; I plan to use Microsoft Graph API for that but I am not sure if that will work either.  Can someone help me to answer these questions.  I have been searching as well as testing many scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign user roles and group roles through AAD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles

You can also manage permissions through roles based access control. You do not need to use b2c to manage user permissions unless you are connecting your outside company to Microsoft AAD, rather than building a custom app within Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

The tenant includes your resources that you want managed under that tenant. It is not exactly synonymous with an AAD because it can include more than just your AAD. You can use it solely to manage your AAD if you wish, though (and even include subscriptions in other tenants that are linked to your AAD tenant).

Graph API is useful for managing more complex user data. Whether you need this depends on what you are aiming to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am however still a little confused with you answers.  The tenants are external companies, but i will manage there access rather than they using their AAD or AD to manage their users.  For that I will create their tenant directory and allow them to sign-up, sign-in, change profile, forgot password, and that is it.  We are not adding Social Network login just yet.  With that I need to be able to assign someone person who will manage approvals and such from a management interface; we will limit their ability as well is why to not give direct access to AAD.

Comment: So, that goes back to my original question concerning being able to manage across tenants.  "You do not need to use b2c to manage user permissions unless you are connecting your outside company to Microsoft AAD, rather than building a custom app within Azure."  I believe you were trying to answer the question with that statement but I am don't understand you answer.  I had already worked through both of the links you provided before posting the question.  Because custom policies and other features are in preview, that is not available within B2C yet; not for production.  With all that, opions?

Comment: By the way, I don't understand your answer, partly, because of what I have learned so far and what I have attempted up to this point.  My biggest hurdle has been not being able to authenticate to a tenant on login.  With that I am thinking I will not be able to manage users within that tenant through a custom app.  I want a non AAD user to be able to manage authorization settings for any tenant within a custom app.